# reduce the amount of code needed when displaying multiple images HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, performance

just wondering if there is a way to reduce the amount of code needed when displaying a lot of images in HTML?

I am wanting to display around 2-300 images in a gallery, and at the moment the HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="scroller>
    <img src="/Content/images/decking/decking-1.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
    <img src="/Content/images/decking/decking-2.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
    <img src="/Content/images/decking/decking-3.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
    <img src="/Content/images/decking/decking-4.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
    <img src="/Content/images/decking/decking-5.jpg" width="100" alt="" />
</div>
```

...but down to image "decking-250.jpg".

Is there a more efficiant way to display the images so that I don't have 250+ lines of "img src" HTML?

The only part of the filename that changes is the "-1", "-2", "-3" etc etc. The rest, including the Alt tag can remain empty.

I am building this site in ASP.Net MVC3 Razor using the ASP.net online tutorials as a guide if that helps any solution come to mind, of if it simply has to be done that way then that is also fine - I just wondered if there was another approach I should consider to learn?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way HTML works. You can't reduce that, as you need one `img` tag for each picture. You may create that code dynamically via PHP, JS, …. But in the end you'll get a long list of `img` tags, maybe individually wrapped by other tags (for example in a list).

Comment: Thank you Feeela, appreciate the explanation - I'm happy to leave it alone as the question was merely just asking if there was a better way to do it (and I know pretty much nothing about how to script something in PHP or JS to do it for me).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Feela, and though it may appear verbose, your code is about as bullet-proof as it gets. Yet if something like JS is something you can use (or are using already), there are options. This isn't tested, but you could set up a for-loop statement in Jquery/Javascript that could condense the code. For example:

```
for (i=1; i < 250; i++) {
    $('#scroller').append('<img src="/Content/images/decking/decking-' + i.toString() + '.jpg" width="100" alt="" />');
}
```

I'm no ASP coder, but perhaps it provides something functionally similar.

Comment: Thank you @Shrug, I'll look into that method as well, see if I can get something to work.